# Testing Spyne application

Tags: python, tdd, functional-testing, spyne

What is the best practice to test Spyne application. Does it have test client like [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#module-django.test.client) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/). I dont like idea to start wsgi server to test my application.

Here is my flask+spyne example https://github.com/satyrius/flask-spyne-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing, we have the `NullServer`: http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/reference/server.html?highlight=nullserver#spyne.server.null.NullServer

It implements something close to the suds interface. Here's an example:

```
>>> app = Application(...)
>>> null = NullServer(app, ostr=False)
>>> print list(null.service.say_hello('Dave', 5)) 
[u'Hello, Dave', u'Hello, Dave', u'Hello, Dave', u'Hello, Dave', u'Hello, Dave']
```

Here's a fully working example: https://gist.github.com/7014099

Comment: Thanks! It seems relevant. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `HttpClient` from `spyne.client.http` or `Client` from `suds.client`.

Simple to work:

```
c = HttpClient('http://localhost:8000/', application)

u = c.factory.create("User")

u.user_name = 'dave'
u.first_name = 'david'

retval = c.service.add_user(u)
```

Ref.: [spyne_client](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/master/examples/user_manager/spyne_client.py).