# How to test RPC of SOAP web services?

Tags: python, django, testing, rpc, spyne

I am currently learning building a SOAP web services with django and spyne. I have successfully tested my model using unit test. However, when I tried to test all those @rpc functions, I have no luck there at all.

What I have tried in testing those @rpc functions:
1. Get dummy data in model database
2. Start a server at localhost:8000
3. Create a suds.Client object that can communicate with localhost:8000
4. Try to invoke @rpc functions from the suds.Client object, and test if the output matches what I expected.

However, when I run the test, I believe the test got blocked by the running server at localhost:8000 thus no test code can be run while the server is running.

I tried to make the server run on a different thread, but that messed up my test even more.

I have searched as much as I could online and found no materials that can answer this question.

TL;DR: how do you test @rpc functions using unit test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing Spyne application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383937/testing-spyne-application)

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you are using a service inside a test, that test should not be a **unit** test.

you might want to consider use **factory_boy** or **mock**, both of them are python modules to mock or fake a object, for instance, to fake a object to give a response to your rpc call.