# How to test a SOAP service in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, zeep, spyne

In Python, i create a soap service with the SPYNE libray. The code is the following:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
from spyne import Application, rpc, ServiceBase, Unicode
from spyne.protocol.xml import XmlDocument
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication


class notification(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Unicode, _returns=Unicode)
    def notificacion(ctx, mensaje):
        return 'Hello, %s' % mensaje


application = Application([notification],
    tns='notificacion',
    in_protocol=XmlDocument(validator='lxml'),
    out_protocol=Soap11()
)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    wsgi_app = WsgiApplication(application)
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, wsgi_app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Now I need to try that service. I created a client with the ZEEP library that uses the following service:

```
import zeep

var ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ShowAccesslists><Access-List><Type>Extended IP</Type><Name>test</Name></Access-List></ShowAccesslists>'

wsdl = 'http://0.0.0.0:8080'
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
print(client.service.notificacion(var))
```

But I'm not sure how to test the result of invoking the service that you create. Could someone guide me on the matter?
I can not find how to make the client walk. The Server already picks me up, but when I execute the client's code, it bursts me. I have no idea yet how to prove it or how i can invoke.

Apart from that throws me the following error:

**407 Client Error: authenticationrequired for url: http://0.0.0.0:8080/**

Comment: Never bind to a pre-defined port for testing. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383937/testing-spyne-application

Answer (score -1):

[NullServer](http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/reference/server.html?highlight=nullserver#spyne.server.null.NullServer) is a good functionalities to test. But to complete client test, this examples are a good started I suggest `HttpClient` from `spyne.client.http` or `Client` from `suds.client`.

Simple to work:

```
from spyne.client.http import HttpClient

c = HttpClient('http://localhost:8000/', application)

u = c.factory.create("User")

u.user_name = 'dave'
u.first_name = 'david'

retval = c.service.add_user(u)
```

or

```
from suds.client import Client

c = Client('http://localhost:8000?wsdl')
u = c.factory.create("User")

u.user_name = 'dave'
u.full_name = 'david smith'

retval = c.service.put_user(u)
```

Ref.: [spyne_client](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/master/examples/user_manager/spyne_client.py).

Comment: please post essentials from the links you provide. They expire in the future and is your answer then still legit to be an answer?